how to create this type of design? is this ThreeJs ? the origin is https://tanstack.com/query/v5

trying to create this type of design
How to create this type of design? is this ThreeJs? the origin is https://tanstack.com/query/v5
i think this is may be 3JS, is there any name of this kind of design and where i can find more about this kind of design.
